# In my Android, How to stop audio recording when other app wants record audio?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

In my app, a service continuously records audio through AudioRecord. When my app is running, other audio record related app like Google Search fails to work.

How to know when any other app wants to record the audio so that I can stop recording to release the resource?

Comment: You're going to want the audio focus APIs in `AudioManager`, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [`MediaRecorder.AudioSource.HOTWORD`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#215) - it automatically will give in the microphone to any other thing that requests it using the `MIC` audio source: when I use that source on PocketSphinx (hotword recognizer), if I start recording with some app, PocketSphinx immediately throws a recording error and stops and I can just keep checking if I can restart it again (by checking if the `HOTWORD` audio source is available) and when I stop recording on the other app, it automatically restarts.

Though.... you must have the `CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD` permission which is a system-privileged one. So this is not a wow solution (unless you're a system app, and then it's wow). But it does work. `HOTWORD` exists since KitKat (API 19).

**Note:** this is for devices with Android 10 or older. Newer than that I think it's different? Haven't studied it yet, but here is the official documentation on it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input.