# How to release the microphone resource when another Android app needs it?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, microphone

I have implemented an Android background service (based in Pocket Sphinx) that continuously listens, detects and spots certain keywords when the phone's screen is on, and then reacts accordingly (for a domotic project). 
However, my app should always have a lower priority and I want it to release the microphone's resources when any other app needs to use it.
Is there any system intent or system broadcast that I can receive when an app -wants- to use the microphone (so that my service can release it)?
Or, is there a better approach or better practice?

This is the log with the errors I want to avoid when another app wants to access the microphone:

```
AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@419c3908com.google.android.voicesearch.a.h@419c67b8
I/MicrophoneInputStream(32360): mic_starting com.google.android.speech.audio.w@41989a30
D/AudioHardwareALSA(277): openInputStream: devices 0x400000 format 0x1 channels 16 sampleRate 16000
E/AudioHardwareALSA(277): error:Input stream already opened for recording
E/AudioRecord(32360): Could not get audio input for record source 6
E/AudioRecord-JNI(32360): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
E/AudioRecord-Java(32360): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
E/MicrophoneInputStream(32360): Failed to initialize AudioRecord
```

Comment: You may get good info at this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html

Comment: It seems such a thing is not possible in android, so my workaround was a dirty solution: obtain a list of the installed apps, filter them to those apps who have the RECORD permission... and then run a background service that detects which app is in the foreground, if such app is in the List of Apps that use the RECORD permission, bingo, I send a broadcast o my app, telling it to release the microphone. If you need the code tell me. In theory this is a bad practice, but Google's practice is worse as long as they don't provide an appropiate solution.

Comment: Part 2: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=61643

Comment: Hi @Josh,  your solution sounds great.  We have exactly the same requirement.  Have you made your code public by any chance?

Comment: Hi @Josh, facing the same requirement. Have you made your code public ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75626887/8228163. If you are a privileged system app (`CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD` permission needed), you can use the `HOTWORD` audio source, which does exactly this - gives in the microphone to any other thing requesting it using the `MIC` source, I imagine.

If not, below Android 10 I don't think it's possible in a decent way (or at least I didn't find any actual solutions). As of 10, no idea because I didn't study the documentation on it yet xD, but I think it's different(?): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input.